# (1/1) FatalErrorException Access level to App\CuentasBancarias::$incrementing must be public (as in class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have this model connected to a SQLSERVER database, use a plugin that allows me to generate my models from a database. But I get this error when trying to access the view.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class CuentasBancarias extends Model
{

protected $table = 'CUENTASBANCARIAS_GRUPO7F';


protected $primaryKey = 'idcuentasbancarias';


protected $incrementing = false;

protected $fillable = ['idcuentasporcobrar', 'idcuentaporpagar', 'nombre_banco', 'nro_cuenta', 'titular_cuenta', 'fecha', 'total_deposito', 'total_retiro', 'Id_CLIENTES', 'Id_COMPRAS', 'Id_PROVEEDORES', 'id_VENTAS', 'Estado'];

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function cuentasporcobrarGRUPO7F()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CuentasporcobrarGRUPO7F', 'idcuentasporcobrar', 'idcuentasporcobrar');
}

public function cuentasporpagarGRUPO7F()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CuentasporpagarGRUPO7F', 'idcuentaporpagar', 'idcuentaporpagar');
}


public function sUBCUENTASGRUPO9s()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SUBCUENTASGRUPO9', 'idcuentasbancarias', 'idcuentasbancarias');
}
```

}

Comment: Read the title slowly and look at your code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read there error message closely.

> (1/1) FatalErrorException Access level to App\CuentasBancarias::$incrementing must be public (as in class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)

If we break it down, your problem is this

> Access level to App\CuentasBancarias::$incrementing must be public

So change `protected $incrementing = false;` to `public $incrementing = false;`

The better you get at reading error messages, the better you will be at solving such issues.